# Skier and ramp projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

[image: skier_picture]

A skier leaves the ramp of a ski jump with a velocity of  $v = 23.0\,m/s$  at  $\theta =\,22.0°$  above the horizontal, as shown in the figure. The slope where she will land is inclined downward at  $\phi = 50.0°$,  and air resistance is negligible.

(a) Find the distance from the end of the ramp to where the jumper lands.

(b) Find the velocity components just before the landing. (Let the positive x direction be to the right and the positive y direction be up.)

I set up the question such that the horizontal distance is $d \cdot cos(50)$ where $d$ is the length of the slope. I set that equal to initial horizontal velocity multiplied by time so $ d \cdot cos(50) = \,(t)$. I solved for $t$ in terms of $d$. Then, I set up an equation for vertical height using $ height = -d \cdot \sin(50) = \,(t) + 0.5\,a\,t^2 $. I substituted $t$ wherever I saw it, then solved for $t$ and used it to solve for $d$.

I got $37.6\,m$ for d and $-2.46\,m/s$ for the final vertical velocity, but I keep getting marked as incorrect. Is there a more efficient way to do this problem, or is there just a problem with my calculations? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: How high is the end of the ramp from the ground?  Also, how far is the end of the ramp from the part of the ski hill that has a constant slope?

Comment: If you have not left anything out, the problem is unsolvable. Unless you know the relative positions of the launch point and the landing ramp, you can’t answer.

Comment: I think the figure hints that the landing slope is colinear with the launch point. That needs to be explicit though

Comment: I think your solution looks correct in principle. I got much larger values for the results though. Be careful with your $(t)$ notation, it looks like a function but it is just a factor. Write the equations out and solve them analytically before putting any numerical values in. Repost them here if you still have a problem. And make sure your calculator isn't expecting radians or anything like that. Oh, and $a$ is negative in your formula, right?